# AddStackExchangeRedisCache and heroku Redis connection strings

Tags: heroku, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to get my dotnet core application to connect to a Heroku Redis instance with Stack Exchange Redis Cache. So far I have:

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = Configuration["REDIS_URL"].Replace("redis://","");
});
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). UnableToConnect on
```

How can I get the connection string so that StackExchange likes it?

Comment: Are we able to see the rest of the error message, or is that it? If it's the latter the implication would be that the connection string is empty (I'd log out `Configuration["REDIS_URL"].Replace("redis://","")` just to be sure it's not that at fault.

Comment: The rest of the error message reports the connection string as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    var tokens = Configuration["REDIS_URL"].Split(':', '@');
    options.ConfigurationOptions = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(string.Format("{0}:{1},password={2}", tokens[3], tokens[4], tokens[2]));
});
```